# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, php

I have this issue:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/html/...on line 1495
```

I have enabled curl in my php.ini:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

but in my apache error log I see this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_curl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_gd2.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_gd2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried to install the curl extension with no luck.

Any idea how to fix it? I have no clue.

```
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `.dll` is a Microsoft Windows file extension. On Linux world, the suffix for dynamic libraries is `.so`
Looks like you copy/paste a bit fast....

Under Linux, you should user `extension=curl` (current setup on my Debian) or `extension=php_curl` (depending on your system..).

Moreover, you have to make sure that the PHP CURL binding is installed on your system.

```
$ dpkg -l|grep -i curl
ii  libcurl3-gnutls:amd64           7.64.0-4                      amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (GnuTLS flavour)
ii  libcurl4:amd64                  7.64.0-4                      amd64        easy-to-use client-side URL transfer library (OpenSSL flavour)
ii  php-curl                        2:7.3+69                      all          CURL module for PHP [default]
ii  php7.3-curl                     7.3.9-1~deb10u1               amd64        CURL module for PHP
```

If the output of the command above doesn't report `php-curl`, then you have to `apt-get install php-curl`.

Comment: The simple `apt install php-curl` should probably add it to php.ini for you, so there's no need to do any manual editing. It does on Ubuntu, anyway, and I imagine it does on Debian.

Comment: You're right.... but it looks like OP crapped his `php.ini` by following an unappropriated tutorial on internet ...